# TD height = total height of contained divs?

Tags: html, css, position

I can't believe I can't find this question here or on Google - it seems such a dumb one I'm embarrassed to ask, but here goes as it's driving me nuts this morning...

Imagine a single-column, stacked bar chart made with divs like this to look a bit like a thermometer:

```
<div id="thermo">
  <div id="thermored"></div>
  <div id="thermogreen"></div>
</div>
```

#thermo is the containing div, #thermored is the full height background and #thermogreen is the overlay that will be changed to reflect data - in the real world it shows percent complete of a task.

As this stands, it works. However, it needs to work inside a table cell (not my choice - it's a system restriction on the CMS). The problem is that the height of the containing TD is (despite trying fixed heights) the total of the two divs, even though they are positioned relatively and overlayed.

Here's the current css - it's not pretty as I've been trying so many combinations of positioning over the last couple of hours

```
#thermo{
    width:140px;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
}
#thermored{
    width:50px;
    height:100%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
#thermogreen{
    width:50px;
    height:280px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    position:relative;
    bottom: 280px;
    float:left;
}
```

*EDIT For info the issue I'm having is in Chrome and FF - IE(8) sets the TD height they way I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem you're having comes from the fact that `relative` positioning leaves elements in normal flow. Have you tried setting `position: absolute;` for the inner `thermogreen` div? Absolute positioning takes elements out of normal flow, and therefore the `td` tag will only take into consideration the height of your `thermo` div, which is set to 500px in height. (Edit: you can actually leave `thermored` with no position attribute. It's set to 100% of the height of the `thermo` div, meaning no matter what your `td` will be 500px in height, and you have less CSS to worry about).

Have a look at the jsfiddle I came up with:
http://jsfiddle.net/dgRCu/3/

Does this solve your issue? It seems the `td` has stayed at 500 pixel height instead of expanding to 700+ now.

I'm not sure what the intended purpose of these divs are so I set `bottom: 0;` on the `thermogreen` div since it seems what you want is for the green bar to expand in height while the red bar is the background color.

Comment: That's what I was looking for - thanks. I have a thermometer :)

Answer (score 0):

TD cells will collapse/expand to the size of the 'tallest' height. Using css within the cells are going to cause different issues with different browsers or especially email readers.

So, you have tried:

```
<tr>
<td height="500"></td>
</tr>
```

And then, putting those block elements in there? Make the height on the first td cell of your table and make it more than the total of the two divs.

You're floating one so the largest should be forcing the height.

Comment: Yup - I'm doing that already. Should have mentioned that this is working in IE, my problem is in Chrome and FF

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the Dev Tools in IE to see how the table cells are being rendered? Any chance you can make a jsfiddle.net of just the html table and css code?